# Junit for runnable class and Queue

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit

I have a Processor class which implements Runnable.

The first method

```
Public Processor implements Runnable{

 //"Event" is the name of this queue
 PersistentQueue<Event> persistentQueue = new PersistentQueue<>("Event");

 //add the Event POJO to the persistentQueue
 public void addToQueue(Event, event) {
     persistentQueue.add(event);         
}
```

The persistentQueue is to store Event POJO

And the run method

```
public void run() {
      while (true) {
       if (!persistentQueue.isEmpty()) {

        Event peekEvent = persistantQueue.peek();
        sendRequest(peekEvent);
      }
    }
  }

 public void sendRequest(Event, event){

  // do something to send the event
}
```

For the first addToQueue method I wrote the test

```
public class ProcessorTest {

   private Event event;
   private Processor m_Processor;

  @Before
  public void setup() throws IOException {
  //the Processor class is a singleton
  m_Processor = Processor.getProcessor();
  event = new Event();
 }

  @Test
  public void test(){
   PersistentQueue<Event> persistentQueue = new PersistentQueue<> 
 ("Event");
    m_Processor.addToQueue(event);
    assertEquals(1, persistentQueue.size());
  }
}
```

But the queue size is 0 not 1. I dont know what's the problem. And I also have question about how to test the run method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `test` method, you created a new queue that has nothing to do with your `m_Processor` instance; it goes unused entirely. You need to change your code so you can get the `PersistentQueue` instance contained inside your `m_Processor` instance. Assuming you have a getter method called `getPersistentQueue` inside `Processor`, then you can use the following:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    m_Processor.addToQueue(event);
    assertEquals(1, m_Processor.getPersistentQueue().size());
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it works. Thank you! But it seems like every time I call addToQueue() it will keep items in the PersistentQueue. Any method to clean the queue after the test finished?

Comment: I assume you can create a method tagged with the `@After` annotaiton (assuming it exists); there's probably an annotation that will run a method after each individual test. In that method, you can get the queue and call `clear()`, assuming that method exists as well.

Comment: That is exactly what I just tried. Thank you very much. And for the second question, any suggestion for testing the run method?

Comment: I'd recommend changing `peek()` to `poll()` and then check if the size of the queue is `0` after calling the `run()` method.